# How to convert SQL query with Unions to LINQ?

Tags: c#, sql, linq-to-sql

How to convert this one to LINQ?

```
select d.UserID, d.Content, d.UpdateTime
from DiaryPosts as d
where d.UserID = 1
/* Friends posts */
Union
select d.UserID, d.Content, d.UpdateTime
from DiaryPosts as d
join Friends as fr 
on d.UserID = fr.FriendID 
where fr.UserID = 1
/* My followings */
Union
select d.UserID, d.Content, d.UpdateTime
from DiaryPosts as d
join Followers as fl 
on d.UserID = fl.FollowerID
where fl.UserID = 1
/* order by UpdateTime desc */
order by 3 desc
```

I tried this:

```
var diaryPosts = (from d in db.DiaryPosts
                           join e in db.EstadosDeAlma
                           on d.EstadosDeAlmaID equals e.ID
                           join u in db.User
                           on d.UserID equals u.ID
                           join fr in db.Friends
                           on d.UserID equals fr.FriendID
                           where fr.UserID == userset.ID
                           join fl in db.Followers
                           on d.UserID equals fl.UserID
                           where fl.FollowerID == userset.ID
                           orderby d.ID descending
                           select new DiaryPostsSet
                           {
                              PostID = d.ID,
                              EstadoDeAlmaID = e.ID,
                              EstadoDeAlma = e.Title,
                              Author = u.Nickname,
                              Thumbnail = u.Thumbnail,
                              AuthorComment = d.Content,
                              UserID = u.ID,
                              IsDuplicated = d.IsDuplicated,
                              FriendID = d.FriendID,
                              FriendName = u.Nickname,
                              Time = d.UpdateTime,
                              MessagesCount = d.FriendMessages.Count(m => m.DiaryPostsID == d.ID)
                          }).Take(6).ToList();
```

It doesn't show me any result. I tried with EF clauses but when I have Union, I don't know how to perform the next Join.

Could anyone help me please?

Comment: Can you provide a sample of what you have tried?

Comment: Yes its edited... as you can see I'm totally lost, I'm new to LINQ

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a [Union Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.union.aspx) in LINQ

Here is a hint.  When things get difficult break them down, then simplify.  I will help you break down the problem and leave the simplification to you.

```
var query1 = (from d in db.DiaryPosts
              where d.UserID = 1
              select new { 
                UserID = d.UserID
                Content = d.Content
                UpdateTime = d.UpdateTime 
              }).ToList();
var query2 = (from d in db.DiaryPosts
              join f in db.Friends
              on d.UserId = f.FriendId
              where f.UserId = 1
              select new { 
                UserID = d.UserID
                Content = d.Content
                UpdateTime = d.UpdateTime 
              }).ToList();
var query3 = (from d in db.DiaryPosts
              join f in db.Followers
              on d.UserId = f.FollowerID
              where f.UserId = 1
              select new { 
                UserID = d.UserID
                Content = d.Content
                UpdateTime = d.UpdateTime 
              }).ToList();

var myunionQuery = query1.Union(query2).Union(query3).OrderBy(d => d.UpdateTime);
```

Comment: I'm trying, I totally don't know how to perform that, if you can help me with a sample code I thank you so much =)

Comment: What have you tried?  Can you show an example and describe the issue you are having.

Comment: I did everything you recommend, I did 3 queries and joined them by Union, now I get this type of error: Instance argument: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List<MvcWebRole1.Models.DiaryPostsSet>' to 'System.Linq.ParallelQuery<MvcWebRole1.Models.FriendsSet>'

Comment: Thank you for your post, I could realize what was missing. The final code is in this link: http://pastebin.com/wvpSfzTm