# LINQ to Entities - How to Convert SQL query (UnionAggregate) into LINQ

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq-to-sql, spatial-query

I Would like to convert the following SQL query in its `LINQ` to Entity version:

```
select
 geometry::UnionAggregate(geometries.GeometryBounds) 
from 
( select 
    GeometryBounds
  from 
    Province where id in ( 1, 2 )
  union all
  select 
    GeometryBounds
  from 
    Region where id in ( 1, 2 )
  union all
  select 
    GeometryBounds
  from 
    Country where id in ( 1, 2 ) 
) as geometries
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8394111/how-to-convert-sql-query-with-unions-to-linq

Comment: See msdn : https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b

Comment: @FakeisMe What I'm trying to do is the UnionAggregate of SqlGeometries not the Union of raws, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In LINQ union all functional provided by Collection.Concat() method.

```
var ID = new[] {1, 2};

var query = (youContext.Province
            .Select(x => x.GeometryBounds))
            .Concat
            (youContext.Region
            .Select(x => x.GeometryBounds))
            .Concat
            (youContext.Country
            .Select(x => x.GeometryBounds));
```